fsutil Quota Query C: not working on a virtualized terminal server
Im trying to configure hard limit quotas on local disk C: and at the same time, I need to make sure that the system accounts n account have no limit to it.
To configure this, I need to click on the "quota entries" but in comes up as blank. So I ran CMD as admin to "fsutil quota query C:" and it comes up as Access is Denied.
Have you guys got any clue? Reformatting the drive is not something I am keen on doing. Its weird, that its only happening to virtualized servers.
